# Spring Integration testing a Files.inboundAdapter flow

Tags: testing, spring-integration, integration-testing, spring-test, spring-integration-dsl

I have this flow that I am trying to test but nothing works as expected. The flow itself works well but testing seems a bit tricky.
This is my flow:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileInboundFlow {
    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    private String filePath;
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReaderFlow() {
      
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(this.filePath))
                                .filterFunction(...)
                                .preventDuplicates(false),
                        endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer.poller(
                             Pollers.fixedDelay(500)
                                .taskExecutor(this.threadPoolTaskExecutor)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(15)))
                .transform(new UnZipTransformer())
                .enrichHeaders(this::headersEnricher)
                .transform(Message.class, this::modifyMessagePayload)
                .route(Map.class, this::channelsRouter)
                .get();
    }

   private String channelsRouter(Map<String, File> payload) {
          boolean isZip = payload.values()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(file -> isZipFile(file));

        return isZip ? ZIP_CHANNEL : XML_CHANNEL; // ZIP_CHANNEL and XML_CHANNEL are PublishSubscribeChannel
    }
  

    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel xmlChannel() {
        var channel = new PublishSubscribeChannel(this.threadPoolTaskExecutor);
        channel.setBeanName(XML_CHANNEL);
        return channel;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel zipChannel() {
        var channel = new PublishSubscribeChannel(this.threadPoolTaskExecutor);
        channel.setBeanName(ZIP_CHANNEL);
        return channel;
    }

   //There is a @ServiceActivator on each channel

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = XML_CHANNEL)
    public void handleXml(Message<Map<String, File>> message) {
        ...
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ZIP_CHANNEL)
    public void handleZip(Message<Map<String, File>> message) {
        ...
    }

   //Plus an @Transformer on the XML_CHANNEL

    @Transformer(inputChannel = XML_CHANNEL, outputChannel = BUS_CHANNEL)
    private List<BusData> xmlFileToIngestionMessagePayload(Map<String, File> xmlFilesByName) {
        return xmlFilesByName.values()
                .stream()
                .map(...)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I would like to test multiple cases, the first one is checking the message payload published on each channel after the end of `fileReaderFlow`.
So I defined this test classe:

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringIntegrationTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class FileInboundFlowTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

    @TempDir
    static Path localWorkDir;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        copyFileToTheFlowDir(); // here I copy a file to trigger the flow
    }

   
    @Test
    void checkXmlChannelPayloadTest() throws InterruptedException {
       
       Thread.sleep(1000); //waiting for the flow execution

        PublishSubscribeChannel xmlChannel = this.getBean(XML_CHANNEL, PublishSubscribeChannel.class); // I extract the channel to listen to the message sent to it.

        xmlChannel.subscribe(message -> {
            assertThat(message.getPayload()).isInstanceOf(Map.class); // This is never executed
        });
    }
}
```

As expected that test does not work because the `assertThat(message.getPayload()).isInstanceOf(Map.class);` is never executed.
After reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/testing.html) I didn't find any hint to help me solved that issue. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that `channel.setBeanName(XML_CHANNEL);` does not effect the target bean. You do this on the bean creation phase and dependency injection container knows nothing about this setting: it just does not consult with it. If you really would like to dictate an `XML_CHANNEL` for bean name, you'd better look into the `@Bean(name)` attribute.

The problem  in the test that you are missing the fact of async logic of the flow. That `Files.inboundAdapter()` works if fully different thread and emits messages outside of your test method. So, even if you could subscribe to the channel in time, before any message is emitted to it, that doesn't mean your test will work correctly: the `assertThat()` will be performed on a different thread. Therefore no real JUnit report for your test method context.

So, what I'd suggest to do is:

1. Have `Files.inboundAdapter()` stopped in the beginning of the test before any setup you'd like to do in the test. Or at least don't place files into that `filePath`, so the channel adapter doesn't emit messages.
2. Take the channel from the application context and if you wish subscribe or use a `ChannelInterceptor`.
3. Have an async barrier, e.g. `CountDownLatch` to pass to that subscriber.
4. Start the channel adapter or put file into the dir for scanning.
5. Wait for the async barrier before verifying some value or state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried your suggestions and everything works like a charm. A question about your first suggestion, how can I stop/start the `Files.inboundAdapter()`?

Comment: The `endpointConfigurer` has an `id()` attribute. So, you can obtain a `Lifecycle` bean and call its `stop()` and then `start()` respectively. Otherwise you can use a `@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup)` with that `id` to have it stopped before test suite. Then you still need to start it manually when all the setup is done.